# Is there any difference in equality checks on right or left changing value in if condition

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between the following two code snippets?

```
if(x==4)
{

}
```

and

```
if(4 == x)
{

}
```

If so is there any great impact in performance?

Comment: What's the type of `x`?

Comment: Answer  is somewhat dependent on the type of `x`, and on whether `==` is overloaded.

Comment: What specifically stops you from writing two simple test programs, and timing how long they take to run?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Because that wouldn't answer the question. It would only provide an answer for that specific example. On that specific compiler. Running on that specific machine.

Comment: Putting 4 on the left was an old hack to protect against accidentally using = instead ==.  Compilers now generate a decent warning for this mistake (try it) so use the syntax that makes most sense to you.

Comment: Type of x is int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most common case (read: "should you not be using an overloaded `operator ==` of yours that would make it different, and should the type of `x` be comparable to `4`") these two snippets have similar performances: both terms are going to be evaluated and then compared.

However there are differences, at least in the approach. For example, should you write by accident:

```
int x = 2;

if(x = 4) // = instead of ==, typed by mistake
{
    stuff();
}
```

this will compile (you might have warnings, but no error), and at run time, this will put `4` into `x` at test time. As `x` won't be equal to zero, the content of the block will be executed: `stuff()` will be called. So there will be a bug as your intent was not to change `x` and not to have the content of the block executed.

But if you write this:

```
int x = 2;

if(4 = x) // = instead of ==, typed by mistake
{
    stuff();
}
```

this code will not compile as 4 is a [rvalue](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) that cannot be used at the left part of such an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Can there be a difference? Yes; if one of the types involved in the comparison is user-defined, then the writer of that type can make their `operator==` overload not be commutative.

However, such code should be considered ill-behaved. Users expect equality testing to be commutative. And in C++20, it will be much easier to write a commutative equality test than a non-commutative one.

So while the compiler will not stop you, it is reasonably safe to assume that equality testing will be commutative.